# Merge branches from 2 different repos using VS 2022

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-merge, visual-studio-2022

I got 2 different repos and each has a branch. I want to merge between them using VS2022. How can I merge them when they are in different repos?

If it helps, in this case, these are git branches in Azure Devops.

Comment: Add one of the repository as a remote in the 2nd one. Fetch. Then you will see the 2 branches and will be able to merge one in the other and push the result.

Comment: @Philippe Is it the only way? I don't want any connection between the 2 repos in regard of definitions at the repo level

Comment: @YonatanNir The only other way would be to manually create a new branch on this repo and then copy and commit the files from the other repos branch to it, then merge. Philippe's method is much simpler, and once its done you can just remove the remote you added

Comment: As @YonatanNir said, I don't see why it is a problem to add a remote especially if you remove it after. You want to exchange data between 2 repositories... If it's really a blocking, you could have a look at creating a git bundle and import the commits in the other repo. But it will be much more painful...

Comment: Also, with @Philippe's idea, the remote only exists on the client machine you do it from. AzDO won't itself have any connection between the repos, though, it will be obvious (to anyone looking for it) that the same commit IDs exist in multiple repos, but this is pretty common with forks anyway.